# ZSH expanded variables in [[ ... ]] do not perform globbing

Tags: pattern-matching, zsh, glob

I have `extended_glob` set in `.zshrc`.

This works as expected:

```
[[ "value" = [a-z]* ]] && echo "globbed"
```

Prints "globbed".

But this does not:

```
foo=[a-z]*
[[ "value" = $foo ]] && echo "globbed"
```

Doesn't print anything.
Why is that and what do I need to set, if anything, in .zshrc to make it function?

Comment: I think this is the relevant explanation, tucked away in the description of conditional expressions in `man zshmisc`: "Normal shell expansion is performed on the file, string and pattern arguments, but the result of each expansion is constrained to  be  a  single  word,
       similar to the effect of double quotes." Unlike in `bash`, this also prevents pattern meta characters from being treated as such, instead treating them as literal characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
foo='[a-z]*'
[[ "value" == $~foo ]] && echo "globbed"
```

`$~foo` notation allows globbing in zsh.

Comment: Thank you. Yes this is it, additionally "globsubst" can be set in .zshrc so it works without ~ also.

Answer (score 1):

## "Why is that [?]"

### First code example: pattern *is* recognized

```bash
[[ "value" = [a-z]* ]] && echo "globbed"

# prints "globbed"
# (regardless of whether GLOB_SUBST is set or not)
```

**Because:**

*In general:* unquoted pattern meta-characters, such as `*`, *are* used for pattern matching (in contexts that allow it). **In the zsh manual**, this is documented separately for each use case/context.

*Specifically for the conditional above:* for `a` in `[[ .. = a ]]`, the behaviour follows the general guideline given above. **In the zsh manual**, this is documented in the "Conditional Expressions" section: the form in this case is `string = pattern`, for which the manual states:

> Pattern metacharacters are active for the *pattern* arguments

### Second code example: pattern *is not* recognized

```bash
foo=[a-z]*
[[ "value" = $foo ]] && echo "globbed"

# prints nothing
# (if GLOB_SUBST is unset, which is the default)
```

**Because:** in zsh, the result of an expansion/substitution is treated as literal characters, not as pattern metacharacters. **In the zsh manual**, this is documented under the "Expansions" section, under "Parameter Expansion":

> ```
> ${~spec}
> ${~~spec}
>     Turn on the GLOB_SUBST option for the evaluation of spec; if the
>     `~' is doubled, turn it off.  When this option is set, the
>     string resulting from the expansion will be interpreted as a
>     pattern anywhere that is possible, such as in filename expansion
>     and filename generation and pattern-matching contexts like the
>     right hand side of the `=' and `!=' operators in conditions.
> ```

## "what do I need to set, if anything, in .zshrc to make it function?"

You can use the `$~VARIABLE` form, as described above and in another answer, or you can set the `GLOB_SUBST` option in `~/.zshrc`:

```bash
setopt GLOB_SUBST
```

---

## Note: terminology *globbing* vs. *patterns*

What you are using is not actually *globbing*. You are using *patterns*, and more specifically, you are using patterns for *text matching*. This is sometimes referred to as "pattern matching" - however I prefer to avoid that term since it is used for something else in general programming contexts.

*Globbing*, which the zsh manual calls *Filename generation* (bash calls it *Pathname expansion*), is the use of patterns for *expanding to matching files*.

Patterns are also used for matching text, as in your code - but this is not "globbing".

---

To confuse things, the zsh manual documents the syntax and logic for patterns - whether it is used for filename generation or text matching - under "Expansions"; "Filename Generation". That section has subsections such as "Globbing flags" - which are indeed used for globbing, but also for patterns in string matching contexts. It can also be noted that the description of e.g. the `b` flag in this subsection states, as its second sentence: "...this does not work in filename generation." So here we have a construct that can only be used for text matching, not Filename Generation, specified in the section "Filename Generation".